# Exception while inserting mail having attachment as a pdf of size more than 5mb

Tags: c#, json, email, google-api

I am facing issue while inserting mail having .pdf file as attachment of size more than 5mb to gmail.
Exception is :

> An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized

InnerException is :

> newtonsoft.json.jsonReaderException : "Unexpected character
>   encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

I tried this:

```
string f_readLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@p_EMLPath);
f_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(f_readLines);
f_MsgRawStr = Convert.ToBase64String(f_bytes).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace("=", "");
Message f_message = new Message();
f_message.Raw = f_MsgRawStr;
f_message.LabelIds = "INBOX";
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.InsertRequest f_ReqforMail = m_MailService.Users.Messages.Insert(f_message, "me");
f_ReqforMail.Execute();
```

If size of .pdf attachment is less than 5 mb then mail is getting inserted.
Please suggest solution.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the client library i would post it on the issue forum see if anyone knows anything there https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: If anyone knows how to implement resumable upload to upload mail attachments in c#, please give example of it.

Comment: I don't think that is possible and I also think most mail servers have a limit of 2mb for attachments.